# How to show callout in Airbnb maps?

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I have a static map with one marker and want to always display the marker callout.

Some folks advise to use `MapView`'s `onLayout`, but this doesn't work for some time now.

I'm attempting to solve it with `onRegionChangeComplete` which sometimes works (it gets called once or twice), but in about 10% cases it gets stuck in a loop and gets called again and again until the app crashes. This happens only on iOS.

This is my code

```
setMarkerRef = (ref) => {
  this.marker = ref
}

showCallout = () => {
  this.marker.showCallout()
}

render() {

...

  <MapView
    style={{...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject}}
    region={{
      latitude: latitude,
      longitude: longitude,
      latitudeDelta: 0.00922,
      longitudeDelta: 0.00421,
    }}
    showsMyLocationButton={false}
    showsCompass={false}
    showsTraffic={false}
    zoomEnabled={false}
    rotateEnabled={false}
    scrollEnabled={false}
    pitchEnabled={false}
    onRegionChangeComplete={this.showCallout}
    onPress={this.openMap}
  >
    <MapView.Marker
      coordinate={{
        latitude: latitude,
        longitude: longitude,
      }}
      title={address}
      ref={this.setMarkerRef}
    />
  </MapView>
```

Any idea what's wrong with my approach? Does anyone have a better workaround?

Edit: I want the component to look like this, without the need for user interaction. Simply display a map, marker and callout.

[image: map screen]

Comment: I'm not completely sure what you're trying to do. Could you explain a bit more? Are you trying to render a callout that is fixed to the center of the map that is shown all the time?

Comment: Hi, @KaiwenHuang I've added picture to my question. I don't want the user to have to interact with the map, just show it to them with the callout already opened.

Comment: Ah. So your map has scroll disabled as well. So whenever you update your latitude and longitude, you want the marker and callout to show at that coordinate am I right?

Comment: I don't even intend to ever change the coordinates. I used `innitialRegion` but then I had a feeling it works a bit better with `region`. It probably doesn't matter.

Comment: Ah I see. So just show this fixed map with a marker and a callout shown on rendering this component. I'll post an answer

Answer (score 3):

Since you're rendering a fixed map with no intended region change, there's no need for you to listen to `regionChangeComplete`. It's really not a fun event to work with as its behaviour isn't that consistent.

`initialRegion` would work for showing your map. Or if you would like more fancy animation, trying using `MapView` `animateToRegion`.

Anyway, all you need to listen to is `componentDidMount`.

I suspect your refs code might be wrong, but anyway this works for me.

```
componentDidMount () {
  this.refs['mymarker'].showCallout()
}

render () {
  return (
    <MapView>
      <MapView.Marker
        coordinate={YOUR_COORDINATES}
        title='my callout'
        ref='mymarker'>
      </MapView.Marker>
    </MapView>
  )
}
```

If you still have problems, it could be that your `title` prop in `MapView.Marker` isn't receiving the `address` you are passing in when `showCallout` was called. In such a case, the call out doesn't render.

Updated Answer: (seemed like the above wasn't working for Apple Maps)

```
render () {
  return (
    <MapView
      onLayout={() => this.refs["mymarker"].showCallout()}>
      <MapView.Marker
        coordinate={YOUR_COORDINATES}
        title='my callout'
        ref='mymarker'>
      </MapView.Marker>
    </MapView>
  )
}
```

Comment: Kaiwen thank you very much for your answer. Unfortunately your code doesn't work on my side. The map and marker get rendered, the callout does not. I'm using react-native 0.42.3 with react-native-maps 0.15.0. Testing with Apple Maps on iOS 10.3. I can share the whole component code if it helps.

Comment: Okay I tested that my code works on GoogleMaps but the callout doesn't show on Apple Maps. But after I changed it to listen to onLayout instead of componentDidMount, it works on both GoogleMaps and Apple Maps. Let me update the answer and you see if it works with the updated answer. Otherwise, do show your whole component

Comment: Hi! I was unable to check this sooner. Your solution still doesn't work correctly in my tests. This is my component code (altered per your answer): https://pastebin.com/0S1fncCC. The map starts jumping around the place while rendering.

Comment: I think the issue is no longer on how to show callout as there are so many things that can go wrong like what are the props being passed into your Map component, what is styles.mapView etc. The map jumping around could be due to the props passing in being updated etc. Your parent <View> within your render also has no style defined.

What I can suggest is that you hardcode in values for latitude, longitude, and address first. Remove the dependencies and logic first. Your render function should just return your code that is from line 18 to 46. Try that and see if the callout works.